# Liaison dans « d'ores et déjà »

Tags: prononciation, histoire

Je sais qu'il est très courant d'effectuer la liaison entre "ores" et le "et" lorsqu'on prononce "d'ores et déjà". Il me semble avoir entendu cependant assez souvent des locuteurs ne pas le faire. Je n'ai cependant rien trouvé de convaincant en recherchant une raison précise qui imposerait ou non la liaison. Quelqu'un aurait une idée sur le comment et le pourquoi de sa prononciation?

D'ailleurs, question connexe, j'ai découvert que le terme "dorénavant" s'écrivait jadis "d'ores et avant". Quelqu'un sait-il si toujours cet adverbe se prononçait avec la liaison et que celle-ci s'est perdue au cours du temps ou, à l'inverse, si jamais la liaison n'était effectuée?

Comment: *Dorénavant* s'écrivait (et se disait) autrefois **d'or(e) en avant**. Voir le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/dor%C3%A9navant), ceci est confirmé par le Dictionnaire historique de la langue française.

Comment: @Laure pourquoi ne pas faire une réponse ?

Comment: @Jylo Parce que je ne réponds pas à la question posée (à savoir la liaison dans « d'ores et déjà ») mais que je rectifie/complète une information et les commentaires sont là pour ça. Libre à celui qui a posé la question de modifier sa question s'il juge ma source crédible. Si j'ai bien compris le rôle des sites de StackExchange c'est de travailler en collaboration de façon à avoir des questions et des réponses de la meilleure qualité possible.

Comment: Je n'ai pas bien compris, ta question porte sur *d'ores et déjà* ou *dorénavant* ? Quand tu parles de *cet adverbe*, c'est la question connexe (sur *dorénavant*) ? Si c'est la cas la question sur *d'ores et déjà* n'est pas claire.

Comment: Je viens de modifier, ça doit être plus clair.

Comment: "Ores" est un vieux mot qui signifiait "maintenant".

Answer (score 7):

Je n'ai jamais entendu personne ne pas faire la liaison dans "d'ores et déjà", cela me paraîtrait trop bizarre à l'oreille...

Pour moi cette expression est figée et fait donc partie des liaisons obligatoires (cf. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Liaison_obligatoire : locution figée et lexicalisée).

Answer (score -2):

Il existe, en français, des règles d'euphonie (le contraire de la cacophonie), qui imposent que lorsque la dernière lettre audible d'un mot est un 'R' (mais cela vaut aussi pour d'autres consonnes) la liaison avec le 'S' final ne doit PAS se faire : ainsi les pédants qui nous donnent du 'toujours-Zest-il nous démontrent qu'ils ne savent pas parler correctement leur propre langue (et les journalistes météo nous infligent souvent 'les jours-Zensoleillés). Non, non, non, nous devons entendre : 'd'oR-et déjà' (ou d'orEs-Z-déjà) et 'les jouR-ensoleillés' tout comme 'toujouR-est-il'. A vos Bled !

Comment: Bled n'est certes pas la seule référence, mais déjà peux-tu citer in-extenso le passage de Bled qui dit qu'on ne doit pas faire la liaison dans  /dɔʁz‿e deʒa/ (car c'est comme ça que je le prononce et tu peux constater que je ne suis pas la seule). Certaines liaisons sont supprimées quand  /ʁ/ est pénultième ou antépénultième position et suivi d'une ou deux consonnes terminales au singulier, mais pas toujours et sans obligation. Ceci n'a d'ailleurs n'a rien à voir avec l'euphonie. C'est une raison qui découle de l'évolution de la prononciation du /ʁ/ au cours des siècles.